# Can someone help me understand how interfaces are working here?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've implemented the following code but have no clue what's going on with the interfaces.  I have two projects: Project.Web and Project.Core.

In Project.Web, I have an Infrastructure namespace which implements a DataSource Interface:

```
namespace Project.Web.Infrastructure
{
    public class ProjectDataSource : DbContext, IProjectDataSource
    {

        public ProjectDataSource() : base("DefaultConnection") // 1) What is this constructor doing?
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Set> Sets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }


        void IProjectDataSource.Save()   // 2) This method isn't even defined in the interface, what value does it provide?
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }

        IQueryable<Card> IProjectDataSource.Cards // 3) This gets me a list of Cards, but from where?
        {
            get { return Cards; }
        }

        IQueryable<Set> IProjectDataSource.Sets
        {
            get { return Sets; }
        }

    }
}
```

Now, in Project.Core I have IProjectDataSource, the Interface:

```
namespace Project.Core
{
    public interface IProjectDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Card> Cards { get; }
        IQueryable<Set> Sets { get; }
        IQueryable<Side> Sides { get; }
        void Save();
    }
}
```

Within the Web project controllers, I have code like this:

```
namespace Project.Web.Controllers
{
    public class SetController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ProjectDataSource _db;

        public SetController(ProjectDataSource db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
```

Questions 1-3 are in the code, my last question is 4) what exactly is going on in that last block of code?  Why does having a constructor for the SetController make the code less coupled?

Any pointers with clear examples would help - I've been trying very hard to understand interfaces so I can begin to implement a Service layer in my MVC application, but I'm struggling a bit.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Provides a parameterless constructor that calls the base class (DbContext) constructor that takes a single string argument, passing the value "DefaultConnection".  (You appear to be using Entity Framework Code First, I believe this is used as the name of a connection string in your config file.)
2. I don't understand this question - the Save method is defined on the interface?
3. I believe Entity Framework Code First does its magic to query your database for a table named "Card" based on convention.
4. As is, it doesn't make the code less coupled, you would need a constructor that takes `IProjectDataSource` (the interface) not `ProjectDataSource` (the implementation of that interface).  Your code then doesn't rely on that concrete implementation, so you could swap it out for an alternative implementation that fulfils that interface quite easily.  (This is more easily achieved if you use a dependency injection library such as [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) in your application to satisfy dependencies and create controllers.)

Answer (score 0):

About questions 2) and 3) - .Save and .Cards are defined on both IProjectDataSource (your custom data-access interface) and DbContext (the base class your are leveraging functionality from.)
They are both public and have the same signature. You want to ensure they are accessed via IProjectDataSource and not DbContext - hence the preceding IProjectDataSource. This is the way to go, programming against interfaces.
The functionality comes from DbContext, which is the 'base' implementation.

Jon has already answered 1. and 4.